# What are all the different outcomes for The Hero and the Maid?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm getting ready to fight the Maid of Windmere for the quest The Hero and the Maid. Up to this point, the Maid has appeared to me several times and has offered me a chance to rule alongside her instead of killing her. Well, I guess I actually do have a choice:

[image]

I tried the option "You're destined to die" and then fought a crazy battle and presently died and had to load. Before I try this again, I want to know what happens if I accept her invitation to rule. So, what are all the different outcomes for the conclusion of The Hero and the Maid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to kill her you gain a powerful staff and return as a hero and become king, if you wish to rule with her then you both go back and rule together ( you gain a destiny card for both of them but they are the same ) if you rule alone everyone will be happy and call you your grace of you rule together they will call you chancellor

Comment: I did not get a powerful staff for killing her, i just got high level loot. I chose the third option. I also got the twist of fate card at the end.